# Suggestions on how to implement this layout on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

Here is what I want:

My layout has 3 main layouts, all having TextViews and ImageViews in them.

- The Yellow layout remains at same position all the time
- the green layout will slowly start to move up/down as the user scrolls the list. When it reaches the top of the screen, it will remain sticky, allowing the list to scroll. When scrolling back, it will scroll down to original position and then stop.
- the red yellow is a list view.
- when the list is scrolled up, the user can still tap on buttons on yellow layout

How should I implement this ? First thing that comes to my mind is FrameLayout in order to allow the layouts to overlap. For the green layout, I am thinking that maybe something like https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders would work. But how about list scroll ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: If this is working: http://sdchang.com/wordpress/2014/03/10/how-to-pin-a-sticky-header-to-the-top-of-androids-listview/ you could create a linearview for the first layer and then put the PinnedSectionListView in a fragment above it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with an implementation inspired by http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/ and it does work for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Programatically, use the size of your list and the item height to set the bottom margin of the Button.

Comment: Note the "marginTop" of the ListView is the height of your button.

Comment: I tried to play with detecting scroll direction of the List and increase/decrease marginTop based on scroll offset. Long story short, this kind of goes when the user scrolls up, HOWEVER, when scrolling back, the List does not fire onScroll because the first item is already visible... so I can't move down the list to original position.